# How can I add dependencies to an ionic 2 app using rollup.js

Tags: typescript, npm, dependencies, ionic2, rollupjs

I noticed ionic2 is using rollup.js as their module bundler. It seems pretty straight forward except I'm a little lost in how it fits in with ionic2 projects. Ionic's only mention of this change is [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-09-28) in their CHANGELOG.

After looking over the [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/guide/#using-rollup-with-babel) docs they show how to [import rollup modules](http://rollupjs.org/guide/#using-rollup-with-babel) 
and for `npm` projects they are the task runner for the app itself where you'd add

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup src/main.js --output bundle.js"
}
```

to the `package.json` and run `npm build` to create your bundle.

So I'm still not really sure how this works with Ionic because I noticed the `rollup.config.js` file is in the `node_modules` folder (full path `node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/rollup.config.js`) and it feels pretty unnatural making any changes to anything in the `node_modules` folder as you'd lose your rollup config everytime you rebuild your `node_modules` or pull/clone from git.

So how add third party modules to your rolllup bundle?

Comment: Just a comment, I don't know if you're using rollup *because you wanted or because it was the only choice* but with the latest version of `ionic-app-scripts` Ionic Team switched to WebPack 2 ([More info](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-build-process-updates/)).

Comment: I missed this. I understand why they looked into rollup but thank god they're using webpack, well see if it sticks. Thanks @sebaferreras